# C coding: Read only floating point number with decimal and reject integer and speciall characters

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code in C (gcc) to accept only floating numbers with decimals and reject integers, special characters, alphanumeric entry.

Valid entries are:

```
1.23, 3.45, 6.77
```

Invalid entries:

```
abc, e34, 834ww, 6, 9,
```

and some blah things that is not a float. 
This is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    double floatnum;
    double decpart=0.000000;
    printf("Enter a floating number num: ");

    while (decpart == 0.0000000)
    {
         scanf("%lf", &floatnum);
         int intpart = (int)floatnum;
         double decpart = floatnum - intpart;
         if (decpart == 0.000000){
             printf("Invalid floating point number, enter again: ");
         }
         else
         {
             printf("Number entered = %.2f\n", floatnum);
             break;
         } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't want exact code, but I need some pointers/clues on what would be the best way to achieve that.

Comment: `scanf()` et al will accept integers as floating point values, and `834ww` is OK too (it only consumes up to but not including the first `w`).  That means you're going to need to read the inputs into strings (using `fgets()` probably) and use the `strtod()` family of functions to do the conversions (and use `strchr()` or similar to check for decimal points, etc).  Your sample data includes commas, which is confusing.  Are you dealing with one number per line?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler User will input one entry at a time and he will prompted again if entry is invalid.

Comment: Note that `scanf()` won't care if the user types `3.14 epidemic anterior 2 4 111111` all on a single line.  It will read the `3.14` which should pass muster, then attempt to read `epidemic` which isn't a number so the `e` will be left in the input for the next attempt, which will read the `e` again, reject it again, and the cycle will continue for quite a long time.  You need to check the return value from `scanf()`.  If it is not EOF and not 1 (it will be 0), then you have to clean up. It sounds as if you need to use line-based input (`fgets()`) followed by string analysis (`strtod()` et al).

Comment: For 'integer detection', should `47.00` be accepted or rejected?  It isn't written as an integer, but the value is the same as `47`.  What about  `4.7E39`?  `-4.7E-39`?  Is the first an integer or not?  It doesn't have any fractional digits, …

Comment: if a user enters 47.00 then it's rejected. 4.7E39 will be accepted.

Comment: Your code to test 4.7E39 is flawed; you get undefined behaviour because the value is far to big to fit into an integer.  Defining that `47.00` is rejected definitely makes life harder; it means that 3.14159E5 is rejected but 3.141593E5 is not.

Comment: 1) Rejecting `"47.00"` is counter to "accept only floating numbers with decimals".  2) Your code rejects `0.99999999999999999999:` as it converts that string with rounding to `1`.

Comment: Another variation on the "is it an integer" theme: `47.000000000000000000000001` (25 zeros, unless I miscounted while typing, though as long as the number is big enough (more than 20, say), it doesn't really matter how many there are).  You're going to be hard pressed to detect the difference between that and `47` after conversion to a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

I reworked your code dropping the `scanf` part and replacing it by a combination of `fgets` and `strtod`.

Checks done:

- valid number entered (by checking if the endptr returned by `strtod` points on the `linefeed` char, meaning that the whole entered string has been parsed properly): avoids invalid numbers AND forms like `42.4xxxx` accepted by `atof` for instance
- if trailing space is added after single number it is replaced by linefeed, and thus accepted by the program
- your decimal checking code, unchanged
- the program lets numbers like `12.455e+1` pass (`124.55`), well maybe it's a *feature* rather than a bug since it's valid as a float.

fixed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double decpart;
    printf("Enter a floating number num: ");
    char buf[100];
    int len;
    char *endptr;

    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin) != NULL)
    {
        len = strlen(buf)-1;

        // right strip spaces (replace by linefeed like fgets ends the input)
        while (len>0)
        {
            len--;
            if (buf[len]==' ')
            {
                buf[len]='\n';
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        double floatnum = strtod(buf,&endptr);

        if ((endptr==buf)||(endptr[0]!='\n'))
        {
            printf("Invalid floating point number, enter again: ");
        }
        else
        {
            int intpart = (int)floatnum;
            double decpart = floatnum - intpart;
            if (decpart == 0.000000){
                printf("Invalid floating point number, enter again: ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Number entered = %.2f\n", floatnum);
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

tests:

```
Enter a floating number num: no
Invalid floating point number, enter again: 45
Invalid floating point number, enter again: 45.6xxx
Invalid floating point number, enter again: 45.6
Number entered = 45.60
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use my brain to tack trailing space. I will try.

Comment: Should not input like `45.0` be acceptable?  This answer would reject that.

Comment: Note that the definition of `char buf[100]` and then using `fgets(buf, 99, stdin)` is an anti-pattern.  `fgets()` takes the size and reserves a byte for the null, so it is safe and sane to use `fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)` (or use 100 in place of `sizeof(buf)`) — you don't need to worry about the off-by-one.

Comment: @chux: OP test checks for decimal part. so it is not acceptable (I see what you mean, though)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler took your remarks into account. I added the trailing space tolerance, that's where I noticed the double parenthesis introduced when I simplified my test. thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for the edit. I didn't think that it was that so difficult to properly check interactive floating point input.

Comment: The constraints on the acceptable input in this question are making it far harder than normal, though accurately converting a string to a floating point number is not easy at the best of times.  Try to find 'How to Read Floating Point Numbers Accurately' by William D Clinger from ACM SIGPLAN '90 — I got the PDF from somewhere online.  There's also a companion paper, 'How to Print Floating-Point Numbers Accurately' by Guy L Steele Jr and Jon L White, also from ACM SIGPLAN '90.

Comment: Note that the above code incorrectly converts `0.0` for an empty line, which then gets rejected because it is an integral value. Similarly, it rejects `0.0` because it is integral. Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: @chqrlie: it appears that floating point inputs like `0.0` (and `47.00` if you find the comments to the main question) are correctly rejected as integers.  I'm not entirely sure that the question is completely coherent; the handling of very large numbers (`4.7E39` for example) is suspect.  But it is the question definition that is suspect at least as much as the code.  However, your point about the empty line is correct; the test should include `endptr != buf` to eliminate the "there is no numeric input" condition.

Comment: @chqrlie: you're right. I thought that testing against `\n` was enough, but it wasn't. I have added the pointer equality test (`strtod` sets end pointer to buffer when failed) and now first test catches it. Thanks.

Comment: I think scanf's return value could be used here instead of diving deep into string reading and converting it back and forth. If scanf takes %f and it doesn't read a float, it will return EOF if nothing could be read. Additionally it returns the amount of parameters correctly read, so that can be of use as well. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: @SenselessCoder problem with `scanf` is the same as with `atoi`: input `45.66xxx` and it will work despite the incorrect trailing `xxx` chars

Comment: Then what of the scanf("%[0-9.])? That will ignore characters.

Comment: @SenselessCoder the snippet you provided is wrong, missing end quote and all can you provide a working snippet so I can try it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre the method I was talking about was expecting a char array pointer, so it was only half correct. I checked the answers and chqrlie seems to use that method.

Answer (score 0):

As you commented above that you are taking input one char at a time then you could count the number of decimals and characters while taking input and then check if count_alpha>0 and count_dots>1 then its not valid else its valid.

Comment: How to deal if a user types abc.def ?

Comment: take 3 variables one for number of digits, second for dots and third for any other character.

Comment: while taking input if its a digit then count_digit++, if dot then dot++ else othervariable++ and then use    if(count_dig>0 && count_dot==1 && count_other==0) then valid else not valid.

Comment: Let me try this way too. I think so that should work

Comment: if you have any problem then lemme know.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want exact code, but I need some pointers/clues on what would be the best way to achieve that (Read only floating point number with decimal and reject integer and special characters).

1. Read as string  (`fgets()`)
2. Insure string contains a `'.'`, `'E'` or `'e'`, reject otherwise.
3. Test if converts as FP correctly with no trailing junk.  (`strtod()` or `sscanf("%lf %n",...`) and is finite (`isfinite()`)

Comment: I agree with most of what you say.  I'm just left wondering about `4E3` as an input; it isn't going to convert to an integer, but it is 4000, which is an integer.  It's just one of a number of nasty edge cases that the question doesn't seem to address.  The specification now seems to say that `47.00` is not acceptable because it is equivalent to `47` — that is not making life any easier, either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's correct. It's a bit tricky one there.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Little reason for code to reject strings that look like a floating point number yet have whole number value.   OP's code rejects any FP input about 1e18 or greater as when the least significant bit of the FP number is in the one's place or more.

Answer (score 0):

The specification is ambiguous: do you intend to accept `0.00` as a floating point value with decimals, although it happens to have an integral value?

Your implementation would reject it, but it would accept `1e-1` which does not match the criteria.

Here is an alternative that accepts positive numbers with digits before and after a decimal point:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {    
    char buf[80];
    double floatnum;

    printf("Enter floating point numbers: ");

    while (scanf("%79s", buf) == 1) {
        int len = strlen(buf);
        int pos = -1;
        sscanf(buf, "%*[0-9].%*[0-9]%n", &pos);
        if (pos == len && sscanf(buf, "%lf", &floatnum) == 1) {
            printf("Number entered = %.2f\n", floatnum);
        } else {
            printf("Invalid floating point number: %s, enter again: ", buf);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you wish to also accept negative numbers and numbers with a redundant positive sign, you can extend the validator to skip an initial sign.

Comment: If I input 545.3, this code outputs   Number entered = 0.0

Comment: I think I should skip initial sign for now

Comment: @John: oops, wrong `scanf()` format and missing `printf` argument and missing header file.  All corrected.